# Calling a function only when another function finishes running in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flux, reactjs-flux

I have a function that follows the Flux data pattern which I call like this

```
UserService.createNewUser(data);
```

and once this function which creates a user is finished executing I want to run another function that follows the same data pattern:

```
NextService.createNewMessage(data);
```

How can i set it up so `NextService` will only be called once UserService finishes running?

User store:

```
getUser: function() {
    return User;
  },
addChangeListener: function(callback) {
    this.on(CHANGE_EVENT, callback);
  },
  removeChangeListener: function(callback) {
    this.removeListener(CHANGE_EVENT, callback);
  }
```

After listening for a change I call:

```
if (UserStore.getUser()) {
// in here is where I run NextService.createNewMessage(data); 
}
```

However the UserStore is being called before createNewUser finishes

Comment: Hmm it's kind of hard for me to see what you are trying to do. Where would you be calling the .createNew.. functions? In a component? And when? Some more details would help me get a better understanding of what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

If you are following the flux pattern then I am assuming those services have an addChangeListener function? If so I would suggest adding a change listener in your component which calls NextService for example:

```
class YourComponent extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this._handleStoreChange = this.handleStoreChange.bind(this);
    }
    handleStoreChange(data){
        NextService.createNewMessage(data);
    }
    componentDidMount(){
        UserService.addChangeListener(this._handleStoreChange);
    }
    componentWillUnmount(){
        UserService.removeChangeListener(this._handleStoreChange);
    }
    render(){
        return (
            <h1>hello</h1>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: I think this is generally right, whether to do it at the component level will depend on whether the `NextService` call should *always* follow the `UserService` call or if that occurs only within this particular implementation. BTW, I think you meant `componentWillUnmount`.

Comment: The change I would made in your code is not pass as parameter the `data` (user) for the `_handleStoreChange` when the user was created. My suggestion for `handleStoreChange`: `handleStoreChange(){
        NextService.createNewMessage(UserStore.getUser());
    }`. And the `listener` for user needs to be in the `UserStore`, not in the `UserService ` (you listen the Store to change)